# Clarification needed for an exercises on general topology relating to a topology being optimal from Arbib and Manes' text

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

The following are taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

A (possibly empty) family of morphisms $f_i:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (X_i, \tau_i)$ in $\textbf{Top}$ is $\textit{optimal}$ if whenever $g:(Y,\sigma)\rightarrow X$ (i.e., $(Y,\sigma)$ is a topological space and $g:Y\rightarrow X$ is a function) is such that $f_ig:(Y,\sigma)\rightarrow (X_i,Y_i)$ is continuous for all $i$ then $g:(Y,\sigma)\rightarrow (X,\tau)$ is continuous.

[image]

Given any set $X$ and functions prove that the intersection of all topologies containing $\cup\{f^{-1}_i(A)\mid A\in \tau_i\}$ is the unique topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $f_i:(X,\tau)\rightarrow (X_i, \tau_i)$ is optimal.  $\tau$ is called the $\textit{optimal lift of}$ $f_i:X\rightarrow (X_i, \tau_i).$  The reader familiar with the 'subspace topology' on a subset $A$ of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ should observe that this is just the optimal life of the inclusion map of $A$.  Also, the empty case is the 'discrete topology' on $X.$

I have a few $\textbf{questions}$ about the exercises that are confusing me.

(1)  I would like to know what are the relation between $X$ and $\tau$ to $X_i$ and $\tau_i$ respectively.

(2) for the maps $g:(Y,\sigma)\rightarrow X$, $f_i:X\rightarrow (X_i, \tau_i).$ I am not sure if I am understanding them correctly.  For the case of $g:(Y,\sigma)\rightarrow X$, is $g$ defined as $g(O)=a$, where $O$ is an open set in $Y$ and $a$ is an element in $X$, similarly for $g:(Y,\sigma)\rightarrow X$, again is $f_i$ defined as $f_i(b)=W$, where $W$ is an open set in $X_i$ and $b$ is an element of $X$? (I am assuming that $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$ are both topological spaces with $X$ and $Y$ being sets)

(3) Lastly, in the part where it asks the reader to prove, where it says "the intersection of all topologies containing $\cup\{f^{-1}_i(A)\mid A\in \tau_i\}$ is the unique topology $\tau$ on $X$...".  In mathematical notation, does it translate to the following:  let $\{T_i\}_i\in I$ be a family of topologies on set $X$ such that $\cap T_i=\tau,$ and $\cup\{f^{-1}_i(A)\mid A\in \tau_i\}\subset \cap T_i?$

Thank you in advance

Comment: (1) There is no particular relationship between $X$ and the $X_i$. They are all just arbitrary sets. The relationship between $\tau$ and the $\tau_i$ is exactly the fact you are required to prove. In the original definition, they are all just arbitrary topologies. They turn out to be an optimal lift exactly when $\tau$ is the topology defined by the statement you are to prove.

Comment: (2) It states right where $g$ is introduced, that $g$ is a function from $Y$ into $S$. It is not an operator on open sets, other than in the way all functions are also operators on subsets of their domains. The $(Y, \sigma)$ notation is just to introduce the symbol for the topology on $Y$, since the category under discussion is topologies. The notation is *not* suggesting that $\sigma$ is also a part of the domain of $g$. Similarly, the $f_i$ are morphisms of the category of topology, which means that they are continuous functions on the topological spaces. not maps between the topologies.

Comment: @PaulSinclair is my interpretation in (3) correct?  Also, from your explanation from (2), I don't treat the notation $(Y,\sigma)$ as a topological space, and that I should treat $g:(Y,\sigma)\rightarrow X$, as simply $g:Y\rightarrow X$?

Comment: (3) No. What they are saying is this: Let $\mathscr T = \{\rho \mid \rho\text{ is a topology on }X\}$ be the family of *all* topologies on $X$ (not just "some family"). And let $\mathcal U = \bigcup \{f^{-1}_i(A)\mid A\in \tau_i \}$ (where i ranges over the entire family $\{f_i\}$). $\cal U$ is just a collection of subsets of $X$. What they mean is that $\bigcap_{\rho \in \mathscr T, \mathcal U \subseteq \rho}\rho$ is a topology on X, and is the only topology $\tau$ that will make the family $\{f_i\}$ an optimal lift. These two things are what you must prove.

Comment: About (2), Yes, that is what they explicitly told you just after introducing $g$:  "(i.e., $(Y,\sigma)$ is a topological space and $g:Y\rightarrow X$ is a function)".

Comment: @PaulSinclair for (3) to rephrase what you say in more pedantic math notation, I need to show three things: 1) $\mathcal U = \bigcup \{f^{-1}_i(A)\mid A\in \tau_i \}$ is a topology,  2) $\mathcal U = \bigcup \{f^{-1}_i(A)\mid A\in \tau_i \}=\tau$, and 3) $\mathcal U = \bigcup \{f^{-1}_i(A)\mid A\in \tau_i \}$ is unique in the sense that it is the only topology 
 that will make the family $\{f_i\}$
 an optimal lift?

Comment: Why do you keep reading statements that clearly say one thing, and then demand that they must mean something else? I specifically called $\cal U$ "just a collection of subsets of $X$". Nowhere do I suggest it is a topology, nor that it is $\tau$. Nor does the problem statement (to which I just added the label $\cal U$ so that I could refer to the collection more easily), say any such thing. Both I and the problem state clearly that is it the intersection of *all* topologies containing $\cal U$ that is a topology, and the only topology possible on $X$ to make $\{f_i\}$ an optimal lift.

Comment: @PaulSinclair sorry for the late reply, when it says "...the only topology..."  Does that mean that the topology is unique??

Comment: Yes. that is what "unique" means: that there is only one.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for clarifying that.  I assume that if it means unique, then I have to show that.  Sorry about my wrong notation.  I still have trouble translating math english to proper math notations.

Comment: The usual wording for an optimal family of functions $f_i$ for a topology $\tau$  is that $\tau$ is the **initial topology** of that family.

Comment: @Jochen I am still not sure how to relate $X$ to the indexed family of $X_i$.  Similarly for $\tau$ to $\tau_i$.

Comment: @Seth You should heed Paul Sinclair's comment. $X$ and $X_i$ are arbitrary sets, you don't need to "relate" one to the other in the sense that you need to "figure out $X$" from the $X_i$.

Comment: @FShrike ah kk.